# How can i fetch data from SQL till a certain period of time

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, count

I have data of merchants and the number of transactions of that merchant with time stamp.

My question is what if I want to count the number of transaction till July 2019, then till august, then till September and so on it will be the count of data of every month till that period, 
I am only able to get data off that month only but not till that period

**Similar Data :**

[image]

```
"SELECT count(transaction_id) FROM merchants WHERE Created_at < '2019-07-01'"
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Do you want the data for an entire month e.g. >= '2019-07-01 AND <= '2019-07-31' ?

Comment: Could you please clarify if the "date" column is the "Created_at" column? Or is that column missing from your similar data photo?

Comment: till July eventually would be:
"SELECT count(transaction_id) FROM merchants WHERE Created_at < '2019-08-01'"
In case you want to extract everything in a query you should consider using the UNION but the resultset will not be really clear to understand.

Comment: Show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a monthly running count.

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select
    date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-01') month_start,
    sum(count(*)) over(order by date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-01')) running_count
from mytable
group by date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-01')
order by month_start
```

In earlier versions, one option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t.month_start,
    (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.created_at < t.month_start + interval 1 month) running_cout
from (select distinct date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-01') month_start from mytable) t
```